# Disadvantages of the Implicit Authorization Workflow vs Authorization Code Grant for Authentication Only?

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, openid

I cannot figure out advantages of using Authorization Code Grant vs. Implicit Flow for **authentication purposes only** for a classic web-app?

Say, there is an web-app which authenticates via a 3rd party Iaas provider. The web-app only needs to know if a user (identified by some ID) is authenticated. The web-app does not hit any 3rd party services and so does not need to have any access tokens for authorisation purposes.

In this example, I do not see how getting user_id (JWT token) directly into the web-browser from the IaaS is less secure then getting the same user_id via the web backend? In both cases a session will be established. What do I loose if I use implicit grant in this case?

Answer (score 2):

**Implicit Flow** is a legacy flow and was during a time when browsers could only make calls to same origin server. One of the issue when using implicit flow is that it returns the access token in redirect. The redirect can be part of the browser history which contains the access token. Also if multiple devices history are synced with your browser it increases the security risk.

While in **Authorization Code flow (with PKCE)** does not have the access token as part of the Url which make it bit more secure.

You can refer [Is the OAuth 2.0 Implicit Flow Dead?](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/05/01/is-the-oauth-implicit-flow-dead) for more details

Answer (score 1):

Depends where your web-app runs. If it runs completely on the browser (e.g. it's a javascript app or SPA) then I would use the `implicit` flow because the `Authorization code` grant is optimised for confidential clients.

If your web-app runs on a server then it's more secure to use the `Authorization code` grant because the token would be send from the IaaS provider (*Auth server*) directly to the web app server (*client*) and not via a user's (*resource owner*) browser.

Comment: The `authorization code` grant does not require a secured client. That grant type can be (and is) used by native applications on smartphone that may not be secured at all. The right question is: `is the client running **completely** inside of a web browser`. If the answer is yes, then use the implicit grant type, otherwise the `authorization code` (with PKCE for native apps).
See https://alexbilbie.com/guide-to-oauth-2-grants/ or the (excellent book) https://www.manning.com/books/oauth-2-in-action for a better explanation

Comment: There is a client running in the browser which makes requests to the web-server running on my server.
Every document suggests using the authorization code. In this case, I still do not understand how it is more secure than the implicit grant.
E.g., in case of the authorization grant, once a client is authenticated, the server will setup a session with the client, which still may contain the same user_id. So it seems it is just a double round trip added to the authorization server?

Comment: @MikhailY it's more secure because the Id / Access tokens do not need to go to the end user's browser.

Comment: @MikhailY the server does not setup any session with the client. The authorization code is used to get an access token (which is used to perform API calls). No `user_id` is issued.
The authentication is done through the OpenID Connect extension. The ID of the user is in the `id_token`, not in the access token.

Comment: @FlorentMorselli correct, and this is the question. To get id_token, why implicit flow is worse than the authorization code grant flow?

Comment: The implicit flow is not worst as any other flow; it is just designed for script applications that runs in a browser (e.g. SPA). If your application is in an app that runs in a server (e.g. PHP) then you should use the Authorization Code flow

Comment: @MikhailY  Why would you want to use implicit flow when you can do server-to-server, back channel comms? You would be exposing identity data to the user agent for no reason. The jwt id_token is probably signed but not encrypted and will contain identity/claims information to a level depending on requested scope.

Comment: @iandayman it's not server to server, the IDP sends redirect the browser to the server, so effectively the client has access to the token regardless.

Comment: @ben  no need for IDP to send token to browser  -  see https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#Authentication  for more info